# How to access size of 'foreach:' binding in knockout js >

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

In this doc : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html iteration is achieved using the 'foreach' binding :

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
```

Is it possible to access the size of this binding via javascript/jquery ?

Something like : `alert('People size is '+people.size);`

I need to access the size in order to do a simple validation check.

Comment: when/where do you want to know that?

Comment: do you have access to the view model in that context?

Comment: `console.log(self.people().length);` in your JS model. Just of the top of my head so haven't checked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you mean within the foreach itself? You can call the parent in the loop, then access the observable array again:

```
$parent.people().length
```

Or anywhere you have bound your view model, you can call:

```
people().length
```

Or you can add a computed observable to your view model. Inside your view model code, assign this to a var named self, then:

```
var peopleCount = ko.computed(function()
{
    return self.people().length;
}
```

Comment: I need to access it external to the loop, but perhaps I can assign $parent.people().length to a var ?

Comment: Here's a couple of options for you.